# Want to change the y-value of a node using Scenekit

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, scenekit

I want to scale down just the y-value of a node over a period of time. I cannot use the method scaleBy:duration: or scaleTo:duration because they change ALL the axis values instead I just want the y value to change. I decided to try to make a custom animation with the method customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:. Here is the code I wrote for the method

```
SCNAction *scale = [SCNAction customActionWithDuration:1.0 actionBlock:^(SCNNode *node,
                                                                                        CGFloat elapsedTime){

            node.scale = SCNVector3Make(100, 0, 0);

        }];



        [planeNode runAction:scale]; //run custom animation on node
```

When I try out the above code, nothing changes. The node remains the same size. What I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:), as noted in its documentation, "executes a block periodically over a specified duration". So your block is setting the scale to the same value over and over again.

Instead, you want to use the fact that your block is getting called repeatedly (and provided an `elapsedTime` value) to animate the change over time. Something like:

```
CGFloat endScale = 100;
CGFloat duration = 1.0;
CGFloat startScale = planeNode.scale.y;
SCNAction *action = [SCNAction customActionWithDuration:1.0 actionBlock:
    ^(SCNNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime){
        currentScale = startScale + endScale * (elapsedTime/duration);
        node.scale = SCNVector3Make(currentScale, 0, 0);
    }];
```

Alternatively, unless there's some reason you need to use actions instead of animations, you can use an implicit animation:

```
[SCNTransaction begin];
node.scale = SCNVector3Make(node.scale.x, 100, node.scale.y);
[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[SCNTransaction commit];
```